# Why does wmic tells my memory speed is 1333MHz, but Speccy says 665MHz?

Tags: memory, performance

I've checked my computer specs, and I saw I had memory in 1333MHz speed. I've checked it in wmic (see pic) and it's true. B ut i've checked it in Speccy (see pic) and it shows 665MHz.

I've checked the [page of my CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/68316/Intel-Core-i5-3470-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) and it says `Memory Types DDR3-1333/1600`.

I've checked the [page of my MotherBoard](http://motherboard.findthebest.com/l/431/GIGABYTE-GA-H61M-S2PV-R2-0) (or [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4065#sp)) and it says `Memory Standard Supported DDR3 1066 DDR3 1333`.

So... Why it's so slow in Speccy?

[image: Speccy + wmic]

Comment: I have wmic 400Mhz vs speccy 666Mhz. I know I run it with a 1333Mhz, so wmic is not reliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

667Mhz is the correct speed. For marketing purpose the speed is doubled because of used [Double Data RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM) which can transfer data on both the rising and falling edges of the clock signal.

Comment: Does it mean that any DDR2/DDR3 memory-card I see does the same trick? Always when it has label of 1600MHz it's 800MHz, etc.? And when CPU/MB says it's capable up to 1333MHz, it suites exactly to the so-called 1333MHz memory?

Comment: yes, same for DDR1/2 and 3. This is done since the first DDR RAM was created in 2000.