# Can't find DDR3 800Mhz laptop memory anywhere

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3

I have a Acer V5-171 with a 4GB bar and wanting to upgrade but I can't find a similar bar on the market (800Mhz) anywhere, only 1600Mhz ones, cant that work too?

CPUZ screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MNoOPKP.png]

Comment: the real frequency is always 800MHz, but the vendors use 1600 for marketing purpose: http://superuser.com/a/773746/174557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/) - they have a system scanner [for Windows & Mac] which will check your computer & recommend possible upgrades